# How can I apply a user defined function for each grouping in Python

Tags: python, pandas, user-defined-functions, pandas-groupby

I have a data-frame df1 as follows:

```
Country|Month|Revenue
-------|-----|-------
US     |Jan  |100
US     |Feb  |200
US     |Mar  |300
Canada |Jan  |200
Canada |Feb  |400
Canada |Mar  |500
```

I want to apply a User Defined Function as follows:

```
df3=df1.groupby(['Country'])['Revenue'].my_cool_func()
def my_cool_func():
    b = max(Revenue)-Min(Revenue)
    c=b/2
    return c
```

My final output for df3 should be:

```
Country|my_cool_func_rev
-------|----------------
US     |100
Canada |150
```

How can I use a User Defined Function to get above output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and in function working with `Series`, so is possible use [`Series.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html) and [`Series.min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.min.html):

```
def my_cool_func(x):
    #print (x)
    return (x.max() - x.min()) / 2

df3=df1.groupby(['Country'])['Revenue'].apply(my_cool_func).reset_index()
print (df3)
  Country  Revenue
0  Canada    150.0
1      US    100.0
```

Or:

```
df3=df1.groupby(['Country'])['Revenue'].apply(lambda x:(x.max() - x.min()) / 2).reset_index()
print (df3)
  Country  Revenue
0  Canada    150.0
1      US    100.0
```

EDIT: Use [`Series.std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.std.html):

```
def my_cool_func(x):
    b = x.std()
    c=b/2
    return c

df3=df1.groupby(['Country'])['Revenue'].apply(my_cool_func).reset_index()
print (df3)
  Country    Revenue
0  Canada  76.376262
1      US  50.000000
```

Comment: I do not want to make any changes to my User Defined Function as instead of max and min I may have Standard Deviation. In that case, how can I use your first option?

Comment: Hmmm, so if use my solution still some problem? Can you explain more? Or do you need return from apply 2 values instead 1?

Answer (score 1):

One more thing you can try if you have multiple columns to aggregate is `groupby` + `agg`:

```
def my_cool_func(x):
    return (x.max() - x.min()) / 2
```

you can directly:

```
df.groupby("Country")
  .agg({
   "column1": "sum",
   "Revenue": my_cool_func,
   "columnOther": ...
  })
```

Comment: It's not working. Isn't it spark syntax?